# EF Core nested Linq select results in N + 1 SQL queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core, select-n-plus-1

I have a data model where a 'Top' object has between 0 and N 'Sub' objects. In SQL this is achieved with a foreign key `dbo.Sub.TopId`.

```
var query = context.Top
    //.Include(t => t.Sub) Doesn't seem to do anything
    .Select(t => new {
        prop1 = t.C1,
        prop2 = t.Sub.Select(s => new {
            prop21 = s.C3 //C3 is a column in the table 'Sub'
        })
        //.ToArray() results in N + 1 queries
    });
var res = query.ToArray();
```

In Entity Framework 6 (with lazy-loading off) this Linq query would be converted to a **single** SQL query. The result would be fully loaded, so `res[0].prop2` would be an `IEnumerable<SomeAnonymousType>` which is already filled.

When using EntityFrameworkCore (NuGet v1.1.0) however the sub-collection is not yet loaded and is of type:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer, <>f__AnonymousType1<string>>.
```

The data will not be loaded until you iterate over it, resulting in N + 1 queries. When i add `.ToArray()` to the query (as shown in comments) the data gets fully loaded into `var res`, using a SQL profiler however shows this isn't achieved in 1 SQL query anymore. For each 'Top' object a query on the 'Sub' table is executed.

First specifying `.Include(t => t.Sub)` doesn't seem to change anything. The use of anonymous types doesn't seem to be the problem either, replacing the `new { ... }` blocks with `new MyPocoClass { ... }` doesn't change anything.

My question is: **Is there a way to get behavior similar to EF6, where all data is loaded immediately?**

---

*Note*: i realize that in this example the problem can be fixed by creating the anonymous objects in memory *after* executing the query like so:

```
var query2 = context.Top
    .Include(t => t.Sub)
    .ToArray()
    .Select(t => new //... select what is needed, fill anonymous types
```

However this is just an example, i do actually need the creation of objects to be part of the Linq query as AutoMapper uses this to fill DTOs in my project

---

<s>**Update:** Tested with the new EF Core 2.0, issue is stil present. (21-08-2017)</s>

Issue is tracked on `aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore` GitHub repo: [Issue 4007](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4007)

<s>**Update:** A year later, this issue has been fixed in version `2.1.0-preview1-final`. (2018-03-01)</s>

**Update:** EF version 2.1 has been released, it includes a fix. see my answer below. (2018-05-31)

Comment: Can you show us where / how you are turning lazy-loading off?

Comment: The lazy-loading applies to EF6. My question is about EF Core. As far as I know Core doesn't have lazy-loading.

Comment: Ah, okidoke... the include you are using to attempt to perform Eager loading is being ignored because you are not returning an entity instance of the type that the query begins with.

Comment: Yh, that's why i commented it out, it doesn't do anything. In EF6 the framework would automatically eager load the nested select query. I'm looking for some way to get this working in EF7.

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to load. `C3` is primitive column, right? How do you know that your query will result in N + 1 db queries, especially with the fact that EF Core does not support lazy loading which was causing such behaviors in EF6?

Comment: @IvanStoev C3 is indeed primitive. I know it isn't lazy loading because i have an SQL profiler running. And because VS shows the 'Opening this will enumerate the values' message when I'm debugging.

Comment: Well, it's showing similar to any enumerable. Turn on EF Core logging or database logging and you'll see the actual queries executed and when.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say N+1 queries isn't that expected? Or do you mean N+1 queries to the server?

Comment: @PaulZahra I mean a SQL query is send to MSSQL to get the 'Top' objects and then for each Top object another query is send to retrieve its 'Sub' objects. I can see this happening in the default SQL managements studio profiler.

Comment: Hmmm... this is one of the reasons that I guess it's best to stick with EF6.x until EFC is more mature.

Comment: Wow, your are absolutely right! Yet another current EF Core weird behavior. If you do a manual join, it does single query. Which kills the whole point of navigation properties. And who knows what will happen if you add another entity accessor / join. Man, EF Core currently is a ... unreliable, switch back to EF6 if you can, otherwise you are out of luck :(

Comment: Indeed, for example I believe Entity Framework itself wasn't really a usable (in most scenarios) ORM until around version 4!

Comment: This is the third YEAR in a row I've tried to use EF Core. WHY WHY WHY do I keep coming back to it and hoping things like this will work now.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver It sure has been a while, but it seems they have fixed it for version 2.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The GitHub issue [#4007](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4007) has been marked as `closed-fixed` for milestone `2.1.0-preview1`. And now the 2.1 preview1 has been made available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/2.1.0-preview1-final) as discussed in this [.NET Blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/02/27/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-1-preview-1/).

Version 2.1 proper is also released, install it with the following command:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Version 2.1.0
```

Then use `.ToList()` on the nested `.Select(x => ...)` to indicate the result should be fetched immediately. For my original question this looks like this:

```
var query = context.Top
    .Select(t => new {
        prop1 = t.C1,
        prop2 = t.Sub.Select(s => new {
            prop21 = s.C3
        })
        .ToList() // <-- Add this
    });
var res = query.ToArray(); // Execute the Linq query
```

This results in 2 SQL queries being run on the database (instead of N + 1); First a plain `SELECT` `FROM` the 'Top' table and then a `SELECT` `FROM` the 'Sub' table with an `INNER JOIN` `FROM` the 'Top' table, based on Key-ForeignKey relation `[Sub].[TopId] = [Top].[Id]`. The results of these queries are then combined in memory.

The result is exactly what you would expect and very similar to what EF6 would have returned: An array of anonymous type `'a` which has properties `prop1` and `prop2` where `prop2` is a List of anonymous type `'b` which has a property `prop21`. Most importantly **all of this is fully loaded after the `.ToArray()` call!**

Comment: Is it possible to have the same behaviour when you later  do `.Where(t => t.Any(inner=>inner.prop21 == "whatever"))`?

Comment: @Botis, i'm not sure about that. You could probably do some testing using a SQL profiler. If you can't find a way it might make for an interesting SO question.

Comment: Turned out it's not possible now. Found github issue for this: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10811
For now you need to apply `Where` before projection.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem.

The solution what you proposed doesn't work for relatively big tables. If you have a look on the generated query it would be an inner join without where condition.

> var query2 = context.Top
>       .Include(t => t.Sub)
>       .ToArray()
>       .Select(t => new //... select what is needed, fill anonymous types

I solved it with redesign of database though I would be happy to hear a better solution.

In my case, I have two tables A and B.  Table A has one-to-many with B. When I tried to solve it directly with a list as you desribed I didn't manage to do it(running time for .NET LINQ was 0.5 second, whereas .NET Core LINQ failed after 30 seconds of running time).

As a result I had to create a foreign key for table B and start from the side of table B without an inner list.

```
context.A.Where(a => a.B.ID == 1).ToArray();
```

Afterwards you can simply manipulate the resulted .NET objects.

Comment: In some cases this can be a good enough workaround, however, it does not suffice in my case when using AutoMapper or when you want to select only a few properties in an anonymous object.
It also changes the result set, instead of returning `B`s which have lists of `A`s you get a list of `B`s which have a single `A` obj.

Thanks for your answer, but I will not accept this as a solution.